# Cplusplus Compiler For MATLAB

Tags: c++, compiler, matlab

I am writing a MAT-File code in order to be used in commercial software. When I am running the code in the software, the software gives me an error. It says you should install Ming-w64 C++ Compiler. The software needs a compiler to generate a '.exe' file. For the first time I need to compile the code by Ming-w64 C++ Compiler. My MATLAB software is unable to download the compiler. So, is there another way to compile the MAT-File programs?